# What is the Emgu CV equivalent of the Open CV saturate_cast function?

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, emgucv

### Question

What is the equivalent of [saturate_cast](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/utility_and_system_functions_and_macros.html?highlight=saturate_cast#template%3C...%3E%20_Tp%20saturate_cast%28_Tp2%20v%29) in [emgucv](http://www.emgu.com/)?

### Background

I have an `Image<Bgr, byte>` and I want to perform a simple calculation on every pixel within it (incidentally: `alpha * val + beta` where `alpha` and `beta` are passed in).  To do this in `C++` I can do this:

```
cv::Mat new_image = cv::Mat::zeros(image.size(), image.type());
for (int y = 0; y < image.rows; y++)
{ 
    for (int x = 0; x < image.cols; x++)
    { 
        for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++)
        {
            new_image.at<cv::Vec3b>(y,x)[c] = cv::saturate_cast<uchar>(
                alpha * (image.at<cv::Vec3b>(y,x)[c]) + beta);
        }
    }
}
```

A really slow way to do the same in Emgu CV would be this:

```
var newImage = image.CopyBlank();
for (int y = 0; y < image.Rows; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < image.Cols; x++)
    {
        MCvScalar orig = image[y, x].MCvScalar;            
        var v0 = alpha * orig.v0 + beta;
        var v1 = alpha * orig.v1 + beta;
        var v2 = alpha * orig.v2 + beta;
        var v3 = alpha * orig.v3 + beta;
        var newCol = new Bgr();
        newCol.MCvScalar = new MCvScalar(v0, v1, v2, v3);
        newImage[y, x] = newCol;
    }
}
```

But that is just, as I say, terribly slow (too slow), so I [read](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Working_with_Images#The_fast_way) that one should use the [Data](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.4.2/document/html/8eaaf685-939e-9365-2bd9-22ef02c39b20.htm) property so I can do something like this:

```
var data = image.Data;
var newImage = image.CopyBlank();
for (int y = 0; y < image.Rows; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < image.Cols; x++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++)
        {
            var b = data[y, x, c];
            double ret = alpha * b + beta;      

            // Eek, now I need to saturate_cast...                          
            newImage.Data[y, x, c] = (byte)ret;
        }
    }
}
```

But that does not do the correct thing as I am just casting the [double](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.aspx) to a [byte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.byte.aspx) and not performing a `saturate_cast`.

I could also use the [Convert](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Working_with_Images#Generic_Operation) generic method, which I kind of prefer, but the problem is the same - I have a [byte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.byte.aspx), I apply my calculation to it and have a [double](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.aspx) but I need to get back to a [byte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.byte.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up writing my own method as I don't think there is anything pre-canned in [emgu cv](http://www.emgu.com).

Based on the documentation for [saturate_cast](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/utility_and_system_functions_and_macros.html?highlight=saturate_cast#template%3C...%3E%20_Tp%20saturate_cast%28_Tp2%20v%29) , I *think* (in that it produces the same result with the images I have tried) the equivalent to [saturate_cast](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/utility_and_system_functions_and_macros.html?highlight=saturate_cast#template%3C...%3E%20_Tp%20saturate_cast%28_Tp2%20v%29) in `c#` is:

```
private static byte SaturateCast(double value)
{
    var rounded = Math.Round(value, 0);

    if (rounded < byte.MinValue)
    {
        return byte.MinValue;
    }

    if (rounded > byte.MaxValue)
    {
        return byte.MaxValue;
    }

    return (byte)rounded;
}
```

So in my case I can do this, which I think is pretty elegant (and a whole lot faster than my original method):

```
var newImage = image.Convert(b => SaturateCast(alpha * b + beta));
```